# reserving continuous block using malloc

Tags: c++, malloc

I'm trying to learn more about `malloc()` and need help clarifying the output. I want to reserve 10 bytes of memory and be able to access them individually but they must be in one block. Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char neededbytes = 10;
    char *p;
    p = (char *)malloc(neededbytes * sizeof(char));

    if(p==NULL)                     
    {
        cout<<"Error! memory not allocated.";
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < neededbytes; i++)
        {
            p[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < neededbytes; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Address at index " << i << " is ";
            cout<<&p+i<<endl;
        }
    }
    free(p);
}
```

The output of the program shows that all addresses are 8 bytes apart. Shouldn't they be only one byte apart? Is there a way for me to know if `char` consumes 8 bytes on my architecture?

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ code.

Comment: And don't use `malloc()` in c++ unless it's really necessary. Also, if you must then pelase `static_cast<char *>(malloc(neededbytes));` also because `sizeof(char)` has to be 1 by definition. And are you sure it's 8 bytes? You didn't post that part.

Answer (score 6):

`&p+i` is the same as `(&p)+(i)`, and since `p` has type `char*`, `&p` has type `char**`. As a result, adding `i` will actually add `i * sizeof(char *)` bytes to the address denoted by `&p`.

What you want is `p + i`, which will add `i * sizeof(char)` bytes to the address stored in `p`. In other words, you already have a pointer to contiguous data when you use `malloc()`. Of course, this is C++, so `char *` is handled specially by `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, and the `std::ostream` class in general. You'd need to do something like `static_cast<void *>(p + i)` rather than just `p + i` as you would use in C.

As others have stated, you should avoid using `malloc()` and `free()` in C++ when possible; C++ has the `new[]` and `delete[]` operators for your purpose.

Comment: Good explanation of what's really happening.

Comment: `char *` is special *in the context of `cout`*.

Answer (score 2):

`cout<<&p+i<<endl;` should just be `cout<<static_cast<void*>(p+i)<<endl;`

Comment: Just need to cast to `void *` because this will try to print the string instead.

Comment: This prints empty strings for me.

Comment: This also printed empty strings for me.  `std::cout` treats `char*` differently than a run-of-the-mill pointer.

Comment: You folk are luckier, or unluckier, than I. I can't even get it to compile. `lvalue required as unary '&' operand`

Comment: Fixed. Got pulled away after writing this, didn't come back until now.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using the address of operator, the offset will be `i * sizeof(char *)` in that case which on your system is apparently `8 * i` bytes.

Try this instead

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char neededbytes = 10;
    char *p;

    p = static_cast<char *>(malloc(neededbytes));
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error! memory not allocated.";
        exit(-1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < neededbytes; i++)
        p[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < neededbytes; i++)
    {
        cout << "Address at index " << i << " is ";
        cout << static_cast<void *>(p + i) << endl;
    }
    free(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the byte alignment of char in your compiler output settings but I bet char is always 1 byte.  Try a few changes like this (I think you are accessing the wrong array element at `&p+i`) :

```
int main()
{
    int neededbytes = 10;
    char *p=NULL;
    p = malloc(neededbytes * sizeof(char));

   if(p==NULL)                     
   {
      cout<<"Error! memory not allocated.";
      exit(0);
   }
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < neededbytes; i++)
    {
        p[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < neededbytes; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Address at index " << i << " is ";
        // Dave cout<<p+i<<endl;
        cout<<&(p+i)<<endl;
    }
}
free(p);
}
```

NB: Dave shared the correct syntax of `p+i`. Thanks Dave

Answer (score 0):

Change `cout<<&p+i<<endl;` to `cout<<static_cast<void*>(p+i)<<endl;`.

Comment: Hint about last edit: `&p+i` does **not** produce "the value at that address"

Comment: No, `p+i` is *also* an address.

Comment: And `cout` will print the string starting at this address and not the address itself. Therefore the cast to `void*` pointer is necessary.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a site that talks about memory alignment on GNU systems.  It will always be 8(16 for 64 bit systems) byte aligned.  There are some libc (stdlib.h) functions that can force alignment for you listed there though.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html